# How to add a subview with landscape bounds to a view with Portrait orientation

Tags: ios

[image]I have a `ParentViewController` returning

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I use

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(onDeviceOrientationDidChange:)
                                             name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

to detect orientation change. `onDeviceOrientationDidChange` I try to add a subview with landscape bounds. But when I try to add a subview to the landscape view, the subview appears on top right. But I want it on top left. Please see the red box in screenshot. How can I move red box to top left?

Blue box is landscape view.

```
- (void)onDeviceOrientationDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGRect fr = self.view.frame;
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation)) {
        UIView *landscapeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, fr.size.height, fr.size.width)];
        [landscapeView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
        landscapeView.backgroundColor = kBlueColor;
        [self.view addSubview:landscapeView];
        UIView *landscapeSubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 100)];
        landscapeSubView.backgroundColor = kRedColor;
        [landscapeView addSubview:landscapeSubView];        
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are masking only to portrait, the orientation does not change, so the bounds do not change. You can compensate for this by rotating the subview and moving it to the effective spot in the original bounds, or you can mask to support landscape.

Comment: Thank you.. I will try rotating tip...ll post the results.